# Can the root user on a machine modify a file in a different users directory?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, root

I was following this guide to set up an ssh key:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-ubuntu-1804

However, after completing I realized I had made a mistake. I had already changed `PasswordAuthentication yes` to `PasswordAuthentication no` in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

Now when I try to ssh into the computer I get a Permission denied (publickey) error. Without having physical access to the computer I cannot change this setting.

Is there a way the root user of the computer could access that file in my directory and change it? Or any other ideas for solutions?

Comment: Simple answer yes (on most systems (nearly all)).

Comment: What's the not simple answer. As in, say the root user is logged on, and I have the file path. How do they access and change it?

Comment: On nearly all systems, most of the time. root can do **Anything**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not solve your problem of accessing the computer, but this question:

> Is there a way the root user of the computer could access that file in my directory and change it?

Yes, the root user could read, write and execute any file in almost all OSs given that the filesystem is not NFS or AFS (or some others).

But the file you are talking about `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` belongs to root not the user, so, it must be root who edits it (or an user with sudo privileges).

You could edit the file with nano (or some other (simple) editor):

```
EDITOR=nano sudoedit /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Comment: Oh, I follow. So when I originally edited that file it was for the whole machine and not just my user. So even the root user will not be able to log in via ssh and fix it. That was a good mistake to make.

Comment: Yes, files in `/etc/` apply to the whole computer, user config file go in home `/home/user/.ssh/`. Yes, /home/user/.ssh/ssh_config could also contain such directive (PasswordAuthentication) which could remove the use of passwords for that user (but can not enable it if it is disabled at the system level and other users could still use a password if only the local file is changed). I hope I am making sense.

Comment: Yeah as I understand it the change I made has made it, so no user can ssh into the computer until someone, manually logs into the computer and changes it.

Comment: Use `sudoedit`: `EDITOR=nano sudoedit /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Isn't sudoedit the same executable as sudo ?

Comment: @Isaac they are, but they provide different behaviours. The advantage of `sudoedit` is that the editor runs as the user, not root, which provides more control over what the user is allowed to do and uses the user’s configuration.

Comment: Thanks @StephenKitt I learnt something today.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using DO you can use [digital ocean console](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/resources/console/) to login as root and fix that file with nano, vim or similar program. Other hosting services probably offer other similliar methods for access.

If you don't have an ssh key registered for root, you won't be able to log in with root without some kind of psychical or console access.